# Changing screen saver settings without completely removing gnome-screensaver and installing xscreensaver

Tags: screensaver, settings

I am on 11.04 at the moment.

Would like to figure out how to change the settings for screensavers without completely switching to `xscreensaver`.

I read somewhere that it doesn't play as nicely with some of gnome's features like screen locking. I also read some guide that recommended installing `xscreensaver` and configuring your screen saver settings there and apparently they were supposed to be used by `gnome-screensaver` as well. But that did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can tune your screensavers via xscreensaver but still use gnome-screensaver daemon to run them. gnome-screensaver has no way to tune screensavers due to its author's religious inclinations. I have never seen much trouble replacing it with xscreensaver, except for screen locking. If you need locking, you will have to make a custom button or menu item.

Comment: But I did change the command line for my Phosphor screen saver in xscreensaver and then selected it in gnome-screensaver but it's still only printing out the default stuff ie hostname, kernel and uptime.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can turn it on/off,select the screen saver, change the time settings and lock the screen settings using the power>system settings>screensaver if that would help. Not the greatest of changes I admit but better than I thought it would be.

More details here:

[Guide to screen savers in Natty Narwhal](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/04/change-how-often-screensaver-is-activated-in-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal/)

Hope that helps you for now.

Comment: You can only make changes to how screensavers operate in general in that dialog. There is no way to configure the individual screen savers like in xscreensaver.